# JSON script formatting

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am working on a D3 JS script. I am writing a function to parse data in a particular format.

Expected output:

```
  {
        "nodes": [
        { "name": "Agricultural 'waste'" },
        { "name": "Bio-conversion" },
        { "name": "Liquid" },
        { "name": "Losses" },
        { "name": "Solid" } 
],
"links": [
        { "source": 0, "target": 1, "value": 124.729 },
        { "source": 1, "target": 2, "value": 0.597 },
        { "source": 1, "target": 3, "value": 26.862 },
        { "source": 1, "target": 4, "value": 280.322 },
        { "source": 1, "target": 5, "value": 81.144 }
]
}
```

Function :

```
function parseData(Data) {
    var parsedRows = {nodes:[], links:[]};
    for (var i = 0; i < Data.data.length; i++) {
        parsedRows.nodes.push({"name":Data.data[i].items[0]});
        var link = 
    }
    return parsedRows;
}
```

where
**Data** is in the format:

```
data: Array[5]
0: Object
hints: Object
items: Array[2]
0: "Agricultural waste"
1: "[{ "target": 1, "value": 124.729 }]"
length: 2
__proto__: Array[0]
__proto__: Object
1: Object
hints: Object
items: Array[2]
0: "Bio-conversion"
1: "[{"target": 2, "value": 0.597 },{ "target": 3, "value": 26.862 },{"target": 4, "value": 280.322 },{ "target": 5, "value": 81.144 }]"
length: 2
```

How can I obtain the expected output using the data provided above?

```
Where Agricultural 'waste = Source: 0,
      Bio-conversion = Source: 1,
      Liquid = Source: 2 and so on
```

Comment: can you paste the json you are getting or the one which need to be changed to the expected form.

Comment: The format that I am getting is in the Data format as pasted above in the post. I want this Data format to be converted to the expected format as provided in the beginning of the post.

Comment: ok do JSON.stringify(data) and paste it that would be more helpful

Comment: {"columns":["name","links"],"baseTableHints":{"rows":5,"visible":5,"marked":0},"runtime":{},"data":[{"items":["Agricultural waste","[{ \"target\": 1, \"value\": 124.729 }]"],"hints":{"index":0}},{"items":["Bio-conversion","[{\"target\": 2, \"value\": 0.597 },{ \"target\": 3, \"value\": 26.862 },{\"target\": 4, \"value\": 280.322 },{ \"target\": 5, \"value\": 81.144 }]"],"hints":{"index":1}},{"items":["Liquid",null],"hints":{"index":2}},{"items":["Losses",null],"hints":{"index":3}},{"items":["Solid",null],"hints":{"index":4}}],"config":{"markershape":"square","markersize":"5","showlabel":"true"

Comment: However, I need to convert the 'Data' format into JSON expected output

Comment: Put the full thing in the question please...if its too large then use gist https://gist.github.com/ and share url in question

Comment: Cyril, thank you for your help. I need to convert an Array ('Data' format) into a JSON (expected format)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105081/discussion-between-rikin-and-cyril).